# Avoiding half pixels using OpenGL ES on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to tell OpenGL ES to only render full pixels. I'm working on an pixel-style game and scaled sprites will start to flicker when moving over the screen. I'd rather have them jump inside the pixel-grid. Is there any way to tell OpenGL to use int-precision instead of floating numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just enable something that alters rendering like this. You must actually render everything such that it is aligned to the pixel grid. The onus is on you, not OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent fliker borders when you draw sprites, you can draw textures with 1px transparent frame, in that case transparent pixels will be flickier, bu you doesn't see that becouse it transparet. Also doesn't forget preprocess you images, so for transparent pixels color will be average with neighbors